# Choosing add-in debug environment between Office 2013 and 2010 (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I am developing an add-in for PowerPoint and need it to run on BOTH Office 2010 and 2013.

I am running Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 and have both Office 2010 and 2013 installed. By default VS chooses Office 2013 as debugging environment. How do I test my add-in on 2010?

Comment: I thought this was not supported by Microsoft: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/06/08/why-is-vs-development-not-supported-with-multiple-versions-of-office/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the .csproj project file and change the targeted version in the ProjectProperties section, as suggested [on this page](http://www.greycastle.se/vsto-project-office-target-version/).